# How to trigger the same animator state in unity5 with script?

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

**Example:**

In an animator there're two states: idle, attack.

In animation transition settings:

Default -> idle

attack(has exit time of 1) -> idle

**Goal:**

I want to play the attack animation whenever mouse is clicked.

**Problem:**

Using `animator.Play("attack");` will trigger the attack state successfully, however when I clicked mouse immediately, if the animation in attack state has not finished, it won't be triggered again.

I searched for some time, only found this: 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/787605/mecanim-equvalent-of-animationstop.html

How to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea to solve this is to call Play("idle") before Play("attack"). The state would transit into idle then immediately transit into attack. However the following piece of code **doesn't work**.

```
public void PlayAttackAnimation()
{
    animator.Play("idle");
    animator.Play("attack");
}
```

I've worked a way to make it work as follows.

```
bool playAttack = false;

public void PlayAttackAnimation()
{
    animator.Play("idle");
    attackAnimFlag = true;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (attackAnimFlag)
    {
        attackAnimaFlag = false;
        animator.Play("attack");
    }
}
```

This works in Unity 5.2.2f1, but feels kind of hack.

**Notice:** It only works using LateUpdate(), if you change the second part as Update(), it won't work. I don't know why, guessing Unity must have done some thing related with animator state changing between Update() and LateUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

You have an any state in the animator stuff, I think you can just attach your attack state to that. Add a bool to the parameters and have it go from 'any state' to your attack state. You can set the bool in your code. Don't forget to also add an exit to idle.
So it would look like this:

any state -> attack -> idle <- default

Or something like that

[More on the any state.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-State.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is the way I used in the first place. Two reasons not to use it. 1 I assume if there's a bool parameter, the engine will check it constantly, which feels like a waste. And you have to come up with a way to restore the bool parameter to false such as using an event key frame, which seems not elegant. 2 The main reason is that this way can't achieve the goal of playing the same animation immediately either. Because you need to set the "can transition to self" to false in the transition setting. Otherwise it will be always show the first frame before the bool is set to false.